# How can I save multiple figures after they have been created in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib, savefig

I'm relatively new to using Python and have been re-writing some of my MatLab scripts. I have a script that creates 7 figures within a loop. After they have been made I want to save each one.I am having two problems, illustrated by the following MWE.

Problem 1 - If I save the figure in the loop it overwrites itself and I end up with only one plot (the last iteration of the for-loop), when there should be 6 plots. I can't seem to find how to specify the figure I want to save to do it after the loop, just documentation on saving the current figure which obviously isn't working.

Problem 2 - While this isn't a real problem for me, it indicates I don't understand what is happening and I'd like to learn more and improve my understanding. Before I added the line

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
```

Figure 2 was empty. I'm not sure why I'd need to initiate a third empty figure in order for Figure 2 to show. In this MWE I don't need a third figure, and in the script I'm working on I need to initiate a 8th Figure to show Fig 7. Just comment out this line to see what I mean.

Thank you in advance for you patience and help with these problems. Here is the code for the MWE:

```
# Test for plotting on multiple figures for multiple angles within a for-loop

#Import packages
import numpy as np 
from math import *
from astropy.table import Table 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

plt.close('all')

# define the initial conditions
x = 0               # initial x position
y = 0               # initial y position
z = 0               # initial z position

v = 30 
g = -9.8 

lst = [ 20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60] # launch angles    
alpha= np.array(lst) 

def size(arr):
    if len(arr.shape) == 1:
        return arr.shape[0], 1
    return arr.shape

[nn,mm] = size(alpha)   #https://appdividend.com/2022/02/02/python-array-length/

#create plots:
ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')#fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()

for kk in range(nn):#= 1:nn
    theta = alpha[kk]*pi/180.0

    # reset x=y=z=0 for next iteration since they are used to initialize the tables
    x = 0               # initial x position
    y = 0               # initial y position
    z = 0               # initial z position
    t = 0               # starting at time 0
 
    x3table = [x/3]
    y3table = [y/3]
    z3table = [z/3]

    h = 0.0100 
    tf = 200
    N=ceil(tf/h)
    for i in range(N):#for i = 1:N
        t = t + h #t(i+1) = t(i) + h

        # update position
        x = v*t*cos(theta)
        y = v*t*sin(theta) - ((0.5 * g) * (t ** 2))
        z = 0.1*x

        """ appends selected data for ability to plot"""
        x3table += [x/3]
        y3table += [y/3]
        z3table += [z/3]
    x3table, y3table = zip(*sorted(zip(x3table, y3table)))
    ###############################################################################################################################
    ## figure 1 - 3 dimensional position
    # PLOT 1
    ###############################################################################################################################
    #fig1 = plt.figure(1) 

    ax1.plot3D(x3table ,z3table ,y3table)
    plt.title('Fig1 Test')
    plt.savefig('Subtest_fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    #if k==nn
            #plt.savefig('Subtest_fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()
    ###############################################################################################################################
    ## figure 2 - 2 dimensional position
    # PLOT 2
    ###############################################################################################################################
    #fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    ax2.plot(x3table ,y3table)#,'linewidth',2)
    plt.title('Fig2 Test')
    plt.savefig('Subtest_fig2.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    #if k==nn
            #plt.savefig('Subtest_fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()

plt.show()
```

The figures should appear like as shown in Subtest_fig1.png and Subtest_fig2.png (6 plots on each figure).
[image: Subtest_fig1.png]
[image: Subtest_fig2.png]

Comment: @Julien "Irrelevant"...kind of like your comment! The code I'm working on is over 1000 lines and from my reputation scores you should understand I'm a rookie. I'm doing the best I can here. I've seen plenty of other questions where not enough is provided for an MWE and people need to create a script just from scratch just to try to recreate the problem in order to answer the question. Can't have it both ways.

Comment: @AlexCushley I see where you are coming from, I think what Julien is trying to say is that these additional lines of code obfuscate the important part of the script you are asking a question about. If you wanted to reduce the size of the included code and get a MWE, maybe you could just replace the actual data with a dummy array that has the same size and shape as the array you want to plot. It'd be easier also for the people trying to answer, as we don't know the context of the larger code.

Answer (score 2):

probably your problem is that you are saving it with the exactly same name, try this:

```
plt.savefig(str(kk)+'Subtest_fig2.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

also, this is an example of how subplots works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rotate(px,py,teta):
    newX = px*np.cos(teta)+py*np.sin(teta)
    newY = px*np.sin(teta)-py*np.cos(teta)
    return newX,newY

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3,figsize = (15,15))

x = np.cos(np.linspace(-3.24,3.24,100))
y = 3*np.sin(np.linspace(-3.24,3.24,100))

teta = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        teta += (360/10)*np.pi/180
        px,py = rotate(px,py,teta)
        
        axs[j, i].scatter(px,py)
        axs[j, i].axis(xmin=-3,xmax=3)
        axs[j, i].axis(ymin=-3,ymax=3)
    
plt.savefig("test.svg",dpi=2000)
```

[image]

if you want to make a single figure multiple time, you don't need subplots. just use plot, like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rotate(px,py,teta):
    newX = px*np.cos(teta)+py*np.sin(teta)
    newY = px*np.sin(teta)-py*np.cos(teta)
    return newX,newY

#fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3,figsize = (15,15))

x = np.cos(np.linspace(-3.24,3.24,100))
y = 3*np.sin(np.linspace(-3.24,3.24,100))

teta = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        teta += (360/10)*np.pi/180
        px,py = rotate(px,py,teta)
        
        plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        plt.cla()
        plt.xlim(-3,3)
        plt.ylim(-3,3)
        plt.scatter(px,py)

        plt.savefig(str(i)+str(j)+"test.png",dpi=300)
```

[image]
[image]

**...**

Comment: This still does not work and does not answer my question.